# Talend ETL Change Build project Properties

Tags: etl, talend

I'm using Talend build Project option to build my ETL job. It will Generate  a zip file with following .sh file.

```
MainJob.sh 

"cd `dirname $0`
 ROOT_PATH=`pwd`
 java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M"
```

Is it possible to change this -Xmx1024M value to some other value from Talend Project properties?  I want to get a build file with  following properties

```
"cd `dirname $0`
 ROOT_PATH=`pwd`
 java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talend allows you to provide JVM arguments to a specific job or to the client Studio. These are then used when running directly in the Studio, built as binaries or ran from the Talend Administration Centre  (with an Enterprise licence).

To edit the JVM arguments for a job go to the Advanced settings pane of the Run tab:

[image: Job specific JVM arguments]

This job will then be ran with those JVM arguments but it will also be exported/built with the JVM arguments specified in your shell/batch script.

It's also possible to set the JVM arguments of the client Studio by going to Window -> Preferences -> Talend -> Run/Debug:

[image: Client JVM arguments]

I thought there was a way to set project default JVM arguments but I can't find it anywhere in the Project properties so either I imagined it or it's since been removed.